# Security, javascript-injection in mongoengine

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, python-3.x, mongoengine

I'm searching on the internet about mongoengine security and i can't find anything. My concern is if mongoengine is treating javascript injection.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021456/how-does-mongodb-avoid-the-sql-injection-mess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoengine escaped string, so is no possibility for javaScript injection.
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=escape

Answer (score 0):

i think it is possible but i personally never try it. i did it for RDMS and i find many usefull thinks in the owasp guideline.  and i recently see that [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection) wrote an Article about mongoDB injection too.

so Mongo use javascript and json. because these use special character like

```
' " \ ;
```

the first ideas will be to sanitize all user inputs. check out the owasp Link.

Comment: i don't know if Mongoengine automatically do that.