# How dangerous is MongoDB's $where operator?

Tags: mongodb, rest, security

Let's say I have two collections in my MongoDB database and an HTTP service which a user can use to submit a JSON object. The parsed json is then used like this:

```
db.public_collection.find( user_json ).limit(10)
```

This is performed by a RBAC user without write access.

Using the $where operator, could a user:

1. Alter records in the collection (I assume RBAC prevents this)?
2. Alter records in another collection?
3. Perform a resource-intensive query which caused the server to slow down?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  If you are executing a find() method and the user has no read access, how can the find command be executed?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo - now changed to write access.

Comment: [What should every programmer know about security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794016/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-security)

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#restrictions) then you basically get your answers. 1. No. It's not a "write" operation to begin with so not possible, regardless of access. 2. No ( see 1), and actually has no access to anything other than the current document. 3. As the saying goes *"enough rope to hang yourself"*. The general issues are already covered in ["How does MongoDB avoid the SQL injection mess?"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5021598/5031275). Notably there are documentation links in the comments to other valid points.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your RBAC set up would govern access to the HTTP service.  Having the mongo find method in function won't allow anything but find/read operations to that particular collection.  Nothing precludes the user from specifying an expensive query. However, a query spanning a single collection is unlikely to be super expensive and you are limiting the results to 10.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great idea. See [Testing for NoSQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_NoSQL_injection) and [NoSQL injection in MongoDB](https://zanon.io/posts/nosql-injection-in-mongodb) for examples on how this might be abused to create a denial of service attack by injecting javascript functions into the query, or otherwise leak information you didn't intend the user to have access to.