# preparated statements with mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb

Look at this very basic php code:

```
<?php
$mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['login' => $_GET['login'], 'pwd' => $_GET['pwd']]);
$rows = $mng->executeQuery("ma_bdd.utilisateurs", $query);
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
     echo $row->login."\n";
}
?>
```

This code is just trying to authenticate a user.
But, has you can see, there is a security hole: It is possible to inject operators in $_GET values.

Is there a way to work with preparated statements like i used to do with pdo for mysql ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why is that a security hole? According to https://derickrethans.nl/mongodb-type-juggling.html, you're fine - there is no SQL query involved that might be vulnerable to the same kind of injection you've seen at MySQL.

See [How does MongoDB avoid the SQL injection mess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021456/how-does-mongodb-avoid-the-sql-injection-mess) for an additional explanation, especially the first paragraph of the accepted answer:

> MongoDB avoids the potential for problems by not parsing.

Comment: There is a security hole if you send for example this GET parameters: login=admin pwd[$ne]=fuck. Mongodb will interpret login=admin and pwd not equal to fuck.

Comment: As you need to get `[$ne]` into the **key** of the array that is used as the input for `Query`, there could be more dangerous attack vectors. If you inject search parameters directly into your query (not only for the values that should match, but also for the left side selecting the rows), prepared statements as used in PDO for MySQL wouldn't work as well, as they cannot use variable column names

Comment: Okay so what is the best way to protect this kind of attack ?

Comment: Which kind of attack do you fear? I don't think there is any, and that was already the first question of my answer

Comment: @Bob5421, with `$_GET === ['login' => 'admin pwd[$ne]=fuck', 'pwd' => '123']` your code will query `ma_bdd.utilisateurs.find({'login': 'admin pwd[$ne]=fuck', 'pwd': '123'})`, which will likely return no records, unless you have a *utilisateur* with login `admin pwd[$ne]=fuck`. Could you elaborate in which way it is a security issue?

Comment: AFAIK, MongoDB will search for a row where the `login` column contains the exact string `admin pwd[$ne]=fuck`. Nothing from that value will be evaluated.

Comment: You can try, i swear you it will return admin !

Comment: @Bob5421 I have tried, it didn't. Could you update the question with reproducible example? I.e. add a document in `utilisateurs` collection that is returned and the exact query string parameters.

Comment: all injection attacks are solved by proper quoting, I don't know what that means here though. Sadly this answer doesn't seem to understand the question is not about SQL

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do it with prepared statements because Mongo does not support them.

As an alternative, the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.security.request_injection.php) says this:

> If you are passing $_GET (or $_POST) parameters to your queries, make sure that they are cast to strings first. Users can insert associative arrays in GET and POST requests, which could then become unwanted $-queries.

It suggests using `filter_var()` for this.